# NGINX serving static files

Tags: nginx

i'm tring to set up nginx to serve my node.js app static files.
The problem is that i recive a 403 Forbidden status when i try to get my files.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name sitename.com;

root  /root/appJs/public;

sendfile        on;

location /doc {
    root   /root/appJs/public;
}
 }
```

when i try to download a file from /root/appJs/public/css/style.css
i write http://sitename.com/css/style.css i recive 403 Forbidden status. why? i have already look for solutions on some forums but notthing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure nginx has permissions to read the directory and files.

Assuming your `nginx.conf` has a `user www-data;` line, you need to give permissions to user `www-data` to that directory:

```
$ sudo chown -R root:www-data /root/appJs/public
$ sudo chmod o+X /root /root/appJs
$ sudo chmod -R g=rX /root/appJs/public
```